# Multi Row Tables Always Vertically Center Content

Tags: css, css-tables

I've basically got a table with 2 rows and it looks like this:

```
---------
|   |   |
|   |   |
|   |   |
|--------
```

My problem is that the second row auto centers vertically like this:

```
|hey|   |
|hey|hey|
|hey|   |
|--------
```

How so right now I'm adding paragraphs until it just becomes the size of the other:

```
|hey|hey|
|hey|   |
|hey|   |
|--------
```

How can I do this correctly using CSS?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use Vertical allign: Top

Comment: Check your spelling, your syntax, provide a specific answer, and put it in <code>.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Some content<br />More content<br />More content</td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">Some different content</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

However, if you want all table cells to align their content to the top, you should not define the style inline, but rather add a

```
td 
{
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

to your CSS stylesheet.