# HTML align table rows on top

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML table. It looks as follows:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Content one</td>
        <td rowspan="2"> Very long content right</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Content two</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

As you see, I have some very long content on the right side of the table, actually, it is so long that it does not fit into what height is given by the table rows, and so the table gets higher, and by doing that, the contents one and two are no longer at the top of the table, but distribute themselves along the whole height. How can I stop them from doing this?

**EDIT:** What I need is not the content to be aligned at the top, but the actual rows themselves.

Comment: Might the answer to this question solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390589/multi-row-tables-always-vertically-center-content/2390685#2390685

Comment: BalusC has the answer to your question as you've phrased it, arik-so.

Can you draw it? Use Paint and draw up a little wire-frame of what you need.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Interestingly, noone gave the correct answer yet, so I'm jumping in to close this question in a satisfactory way.

What you really need is the `valign='baseline'` CSS property to align the first text lines of the `<td>` elements.

```
td {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Comment: Niiice... why only 5 rainbows when the other answer has 26? you should have more.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to TD to be aligned at the top you need to set the vertical-align of the TR in the CSS not the TD

Answer (score -3):

```
<td valign='top' >
```

Answer (score -4):

May be you use the div for internal scroll option without disturbing the page height.

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with the question.